# java.io.EOFException When trying to read a serialized object

Tags: java, exception, inputstream, fileinputstream

I have a serialized a data object into a file and tried to read that object back inside a servelet.Im getting below exception

```
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

my code is

```
FileInputStream fin;
    try
    {
        fin = new FileInputStream( "G:\\search\\webapp\\DataManager\\WSList" );
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( fin );
        InfoRpc newObj = ( InfoRpc ) ois.readObject();
        newObj.getCategories();
        ois.close();
        return newObj;
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any idea ?

Comment: what does getCategories do?

Comment: its just a method in the object that i read from the file. Exception throws after executing ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( fin );